# using webbrowser to make a link (Python)

Tags: python, hyperlink

I made some code where it tells you date and time and I want it to have a link at the bottom where if you click it it will take you to a time website (I used a random google search and found a website)

I currently have the import webbrowser and webbrowser.open("The link", new=2) but I want it to just be the words with a link attached. I saw and looked at the hyperlink format and didn't really understand it so I am now posting a question.

Is there a way to make a link (Of just words) that can take you to a website. If I have to use the hyperlink format try and describe the best way to use it. Thank you.

https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/

That is the link I am using ^^

Comment: When you say "I want it to have a link at the bottom" What do you mean? Have the link where? On a website? In a text file? In markdown? Or html? In the console? That changes everything.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad. In the console. My code prints out time date and weather status, at the bottom of the console (below all of the print statements) is where I want the link.

Answer (score 0):

The shell in python does not support hyperlinks. That being said there are other options you have, the easiest being the following:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("link")
```

This is not clickable, but will open your webbrowser and open the link in it.

Alternatively write to a index.html file, in which case you would need to use the html hyperlink syntax

```
<a href="link">text</a>
```

Then you can either serve that file as a website or open it with a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a clickable button, you should try with html.